# Excel lookup function to look for multi word cell for multi result

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup, xlookup

I was looking at this post: https://www.exceldemy.com/vlookup-if-cell-contains-a-word-within-text-in-excel/ and wondered is it possible to do something like put "A14, Snapdragon" as the lookup word in one cell and the function would reply list of all possible lookup results "iPhone 12, Xiaomi Mi 11 Pro" also in one cell.

Comment: It is possible with Excel 2019 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ***EXCEL-365*** then give a try on below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,XLOOKUP("*"&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A14,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&"*",A2:A9,B2:B9,,2))
```

[image]

Comment: OP is looking to look for comma-delimited values and return the results as a comma-delimited value too.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @Harun24HR Thx! What are the "<t><s>" and why does this function not work when there is a '&' sign in the lookup table names?

Comment: @T-RexMan I would recommend to read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) for more details and clarification.

Comment: @Harun24HR Thanks! So What should I do lets say if one of my chipsets was called "A14&Bionic" instead?

Comment: @T-RexMan Then we need few extra function to substitute `&` and after getting result, reform `&` to result. That would be long formula.

Comment: Just a FYI, but `FILTERXML()` will return the ampersand back in it's original form. No need to use multiple `SUBSTITUTE()` functions. Just one will =)